# Why onFocusChangeListener works only when top button been clicked - Android

Tags: android

I need to use keyboard arrows clicks. I have a gridView and I set onFocusChangeListener.
I have TextView on top / gridView in the middle / ImageView in the bottom.
According the logs it works the focusChangeListener trigger only if I go from bottom ImageView to the gridView with top arrow button. But callback does not trigger when I jumps from top TextView to the middle gridView with down button arrow clicked.

How to make callback works all the time? My code is pretty simple

```
gridView.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, b ->
            Log.d("test", $b)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the setOnClickListener() for listen the click event instead.
Cuz forcusChangeListener only works on the forcus has been changed.

Comment: no click triggers the execution code. but focus is for navigation purpose only